# VBA Runtime error 1004 on If statement

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Good day to all,
I keep getting the same runtime error while executing my code. I don't have formal training in VBA (mostly some VB in highschool).
The code is this

```
Sub Lavaggi2():
Dim i, j, k, lavaggio, x, daymax As Integer
Dim day As Date
Dim Ore(10) As Single
Dim column_len, row_len As Integer
Dim totale_ore As Integer

'Determining variable for row and columns
column_len = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
row_len = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
k = 1

For j = 1 To row_len
    For i = 1 To column_len
        If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(2, i).Value = "Codice") Then
            If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i).Value = "00/100" Or Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i).Value = "00/200") Then
                day = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, 1).Value
                    For k = 1 To 10
                        If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, 1).Value = day) Then
                            Ore(k) = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, i + 5).Value
                            daymax = daymax + 1
                            Else
                        End If
                    Next k
                totale_ore = Worksheet.funcion.Sum(Ore)
                lavaggio = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i + 7) / totale_ore
                    For x = 1 To daymax
                        Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - x, i + 7).Value = lavaggio * Ore(x)
                    Next x
                Erase Ore
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

The line where I get the error is

```
   If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, 1).Value = day) Then
```

I'm quite sure it's something silly but I'm unable to wrap my head around it.

PS: I'm aware that the code is probably a little clunky but I'll streamline it at a future stage.

Thanks to all who will answer

Comment: What are the values of `j`, `k` and `i` when the error happens?

Comment: the first instance the cycle triggers should be j=6, i=3 and k=1

Comment: I get *should be*, but did you try toggling a breakpoint (F9) and stepping through your code (F8) and looking at your *locals* (Alt+V,S) to **know** what the values are?

Comment: The error happens on j=6, i=3 and k=6 so it's in fact a matter of not existing cell... the fact is that k started at 1 and by the time I get the error, daymax has value of 3 (so it cycled 3 times in the If and 3 in the else)...

Comment: Ok, I seemed to have solved the issue by forcing the end of the if cycle

`If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, 1).Value = day) Then
                            Ore(k) = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, i + 5).Value
                            daymax = daymax + 1
                            Else
                            **k=10**
                        End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issues I encountered. It works as intended. Thanks to all for the help

```
Sub Lavaggi2():
Dim i, j, k, x, daymax As Integer
Dim day As Date
Dim lavaggio, totale_ore, Ore(10) As Double
Dim column_len, row_len As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

column_len = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
row_len = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

daymax = 1
For j = 1 To row_len
    For i = 1 To column_len
        If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(2, i).Value = "Codice") Then
            If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i).Value = "00/100" Or Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i).Value = "00/200") Then
                day = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, 1).Value
                    For k = 1 To 10
                        If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, 1).Value = day) Then
                            Ore(k) = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, i + 5).Value
                            daymax = daymax + 1
                            Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                totale_ore = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Ore)
                lavaggio = Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j, i + 7) / totale_ore
                    For x = 1 To daymax - 1
                        Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - x, i + 7).Value = lavaggio * Ore(x)
                    Next x
                daymax = 1
                Erase Ore
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I also tweaked the declarations in order to achieve the desired precision in the final results.

Answer (score 2):

On your first iteration of the loop, `j - k` would equal 0, and your cell would be `.Cells(0, 1)`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: The first cell that meets the criteria of being either `00/100` or `00/200` is cell C6, this would equal  j=6, i=3 and k=1 so j-k is 5, thus it checks cell A5 which exists.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Khellendros As Mat suggested, put `MsgBox i & " " & j & " " & k` before your `If (Sheets("Foglio7").Cells(j - k, i).Value = day)` line and see what those values are.